# Engine loses power at certain rpm once it gets hot

Tags: engine, motorcycle, overheating, rpm

I have a Pulsar 220 which starts good but after riding few kms, engine starts getting too hot. Even the high temp and oil change sign starts blinking. There is no issue with engine oil. As I get it changed timely from authorised mechanic and is using motul 5100 semi synthetic oil.

The main problem is that when it gets hot, the engine seems to behave abnormally. On RPM higher than 4000 on any gear it only produces vibration and sound without any significant power delivery. Feels like being dragged by something. I can’t even throttle at once as it doesn’t delivers power and only vibrates and produces revving sound. At low throttle it gains speed slowly without any problem. The other problem is that even though I press clutch and loosen throttle from higher rpm to slow down the rpm doesn’t go down as it should and keeps roaring at 2000 rpm. I have to rev match the engine while slowly speeding down to get it to lower rpm.

I tried disconnecting auto choke. Checked spark plug. Lowering and increasing the idle rpm. Nothing helped. Even the mechanic seems to be confused and did all he could do to fix the problem.

Interesting fact it cruises well in rainy weather as the splattering water keeps engine slightly cool and none of the problem turns up.

Comment: All the symptoms of poor performance are common with an overheating engine. Once you solve the overheating problem the engine should return to normal (assuming it's not been damaged along the way).  Your engine has an oil cooling radiator - I am unfamiliar with the general plumbing of such a device. It could be that the flow through the radiator has been cut-off, reduced.  Is there a way to check that?  Is there a thermostat of sorts?

Comment: Well I cleaned the radiator fin with water jet quite a times and tried rotating the oil pressure screw of radiator. I guess it could be a problem with the flow tubes, I will get those checked in a day or two. Could there be any other reason of heating?